# Virtual Assistant Program: Python Unable to Find Variable

Tags: python, variables, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

Basically, the program is a virtual assistant made to take in audio input and transform it into text/string input, which will be stored in the variable 'command'. This is so that the program can then check if certain keywords exist in 'command' and return appropriate responses.

(e.g., if command is 'assistant, tell me the time', program will output 'Current time is 3:40 pm')

Here is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    global command
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('Listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()

            if 'assistant' in command:
                command = command.replace('assistant', '')
                print(command)
            return command
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        return command


def run():
    command = take_command()

    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk(f'playing {song}')
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)

    if 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        print(time)
        talk(f'Current time is {time}')

    if 'who is' in command:
        person = command.replace('who is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)

    elif 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    else:
       talk('please repeat that command')


def main():
    run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the output I receive:

```
Listening...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\21018018\Documents\4 VSC\1 py\artificial_intelligence\alexa\main.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\21018018\Documents\4 VSC\1 py\artificial_intelligence\alexa\main.py", line 69, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\21018018\Documents\4 VSC\1 py\artificial_intelligence\alexa\main.py", line 40, in run
    command = take_command()
  File "c:\Users\21018018\Documents\4 VSC\1 py\artificial_intelligence\alexa\main.py", line 36, in take_command
    return command
NameError: name 'command' is not defined
```

I have tried:

- Adding 'finally: return command' in 'take_command()' function.
- Adding 'global command' in 'take_command()' function.
- Rewriting the code with reference to a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWvsXxDtEkU&feature=youtu.be)

Thank you! I appreciate your time.

Comment: You can't return `command` in your `finally` block if it hasn't been defined, which is the case if an exception occured.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `global command` in the `take_command()` function as the `command` variable not declared globally and there is no use in declaring it globally.